# SVG hide overflow after top rect border stroke

Tags: javascript, html, svg

How can I hide overflowing red color in this SVG? I tried moving it before the rect with the stroke, but it's not helping.

Here's the code and a screenshot.

```html
<br><br>
<svg _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" xml:space="preserve" style="max-width: 100%;" id="15875450744052" height="34">
  
  <g _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" id="canvas1-group2">
    
    <rect _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" stroke="null" x="2" y="2" id="15875450744052-wan-rate-3fa119cb-0555-4094-a0a6-33a8ac11b772-DOWN" width="0.4%" fill="red" height="30" rx="15" ry="15"></rect>
    <rect _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" stroke-width="2" fill="" fill-opacity="1" x="1" y="1" id="15875450744052-isp-speed-3fa119cb-0555-4094-a0a6-33a8ac11b772-DOWN" stroke="#D4D4D4" width="99%" height="32" rx="15" ry="15" style="
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: 20;
"></rect>
    

    <text _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" x="31%" y="20" font-family="Verdana" font-size="12px" fill="#222222">
      4.0
    </text>
    <text _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" x="64%" y="20" font-family="Verdana" font-size="12px" fill="#222222">
      16.2
    </text>
    <text _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" x="90%" y="20" font-family="Verdana" font-size="12px" fill="#222222">
      81
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've moved the large rounded rect into a clipPath and applied that clipPath to the red rect.

I've then used a `<use>` element to render the original rect that's now in the clipPath.

```html
<br><br>
<svg _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" xml:space="preserve" style="max-width: 100%;" id="15875450744052" height="34">
  
  <g _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" id="canvas1-group2">
  
      <clipPath id="cp">
        <rect id="r" _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" stroke-width="2" fill="" fill-opacity="1" x="1" y="1" id="15875450744052-isp-speed-3fa119cb-0555-4094-a0a6-33a8ac11b772-DOWN" stroke="#D4D4D4" width="99%" height="32" rx="15" ry="15" style="
    overflow: hidden;
    background: red;
    padding: 20px;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: 20;
"></rect>
    </clipPath>  
    <rect _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" stroke="null" x="2" y="2" id="15875450744052-wan-rate-3fa119cb-0555-4094-a0a6-33a8ac11b772-DOWN" width="0.4%" fill="red" height="30" rx="15" ry="15" clip-path="url(#cp)"></rect>
    <use xlink:href="#r"/>

    <text _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" x="31%" y="20" font-family="Verdana" font-size="12px" fill="#222222">
      4.0
    </text>
    <text _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" x="64%" y="20" font-family="Verdana" font-size="12px" fill="#222222">
      16.2
    </text>
    <text _ngcontent-fdl-c107="" x="90%" y="20" font-family="Verdana" font-size="12px" fill="#222222">
      81
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks Robert :)